# How Do I Decode/Encode A Video To A Text File and then Back To Video?

Tags: python

I want to take a video - take the video contents - and turn it into base64. Then, I want to take that text file - decode it from base64 - and then turn it back into a video.

Currently, I have been able to turn the video into a text file, but when I try to convert it back into a video I get an empty text file instead of a video file.

How do I fix this?

```
import base64



with open("al.mp4", "rb") as videoFile:
    text = base64.b64encode(videoFile.read())
    print(text)
    file = open("textTest.txt", "wb") 
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

    fh = open("video.mp4", "wb")
    fh.write(base64.b64decode(str))
    fh.close()
```

Comment: You are not writing anything to the mp4 file. `str` is an empty string here.

Comment: Using names of built-in Python functions or types like `str` is not recommended.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated it @nullptr - same error though

Comment: Now `str` is the builtin string type. It can't be written to a file.

Comment: Can you explain that? I don't quite understand what it is, or how to fix it

Comment: With `base64.b64decode(str)` you try to decode `str` but `str` was initially just the empty string, after your edit it is the built-in string type of Python.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
import base64



with open("al.mp4", "rb") as videoFile:
    text = base64.b64encode(videoFile.read())
    print(text)
    file = open("textTest.txt", "wb") 
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

    fh = open("video.mp4", "wb")
    fh.write(base64.b64decode(text))
    fh.close()
```

This is the code that works.
You were trying to write `str` to the file. Now `str` in python is the name of the string class. You can do something like `str = "assda"` but that is not recommended. And furthermore, `str` is not the stuff you just read from the file. That is `text`. Just write `text` and you're good.

Comment: here you have used the same ```text``` variable to write in ```video.mp4``` file . but how will i write it from ```textTest,txt``` file